# iOS 7 - UITableView does not stay highlighted

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Sorry if this is a simple problem, but my code does not seem to work properly. I want to keep the selected rows in a tableView highlighted after the user selects it.

I have 2 arrays where I take the price and item name from. I have a third array that keeps track of which row was selected so I know which ones have been selected already.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method where I assign the text label and the check mark.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *ItemCellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    //SearchresultTableViewCell is my own class for the tableViewCell
    SearchResultTableViewCell *tableCell =(SearchResultTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ItemCellIdentifier];

    //set text labels here
    [tableCell.price setText:[NSString stringWithString:[priceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [tableCell.itemName setText:[NSString stringWithString:[itemNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    //set check mark and highlights.
    if ([[checkList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue] == 1){
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [tableCell setHighlighted:YES];
    }

    else{
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [tableCell setHighlighted:NO];
    }

    return tableCell;

}
```

And here is he `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. What I basically do here is I mark the object as checked by editing my `checkList` array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"did select row at index path entered");
    if ([[checkList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue] == 1){
        [checkList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];

    }
    else{
        [checkList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"1"];
    }
    [self.searchResults reloadData];
}
```

I have tried `[tableCell setHighlighted:TRUE];` and `[tableCell setHighlighted:1];` but it does not work.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `self.searchResults` is your tableView? Sending the `reloadData` message will cause the tableView to refresh itself and unselect selected cells.

Comment: Yes, `searchResults` is my tableView. So how do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for answering my comment. As I mentioned, sending the `reloadData` message will cause the currently selected cells to be deselected. Therefore, you should cache the currently selected cells just before reloading the tableView and restore them afterwards. I'm thinking something like this:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [self.searchResults indexPathsForSelectedRows];

[self.searchResults reloadData];

for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
    [self.searchResults selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

This should work as long as you aren't inserting/deleting/moving rows. If you are, you'll have to account for that.

Comment: This worked. Thank you, I had to enable multiple selection as r.szeja suggested.

Comment: One problem though, when I click the cell, it highlights and places the checkmark. When I click it again, the highlight is removed but the checkmark remains. On the third click, I get a highlight but no checkmark, and on the fourth click, I finally clear out the highlight and checkmark.

Comment: Honestly I'm running out the door, but I'm not sure I have enough info to debug that. Not exactly sure what it is, and I don't know what's going on in your subclass. Are you mutating the relevant objects anywhere? Btw, not that it matters, but instead of using a string `"1"` you can wrap a number literal in NSNumber like @(1) and just add NSNumbers to your arrays instead of NSStrings.

Comment: I think I have to unselect/select the rows properly in my if-else block in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to call `setSelected:` not `setHighlighted`, please try replacing your `[tableCell setHighlighted:YES];` with `[tableCell setSelected:YES];`

Moreover, I noticed that simply calling `[tableCell setSelected:YES];` does not always select the row, so if `setSelected` still does not work, please try replacing `[tableCell setHighlighted:YES];` with following:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                            animated:YES 
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

You can comment out `[tableCell setHighlighted:NO];` since when you reload your table it will automatically get un selected.

This is how your code should look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *ItemCellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    //SearchresultTableViewCell is my own class for the tableViewCell
    SearchResultTableViewCell *tableCell =(SearchResultTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ItemCellIdentifier];

    //set text labels here
    [tableCell.price setText:[NSString stringWithString:[priceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [tableCell.itemName setText:[NSString stringWithString:[itemNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    //set check mark and highlights.
    if ([[checkList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue] == 1){
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        // [tableCell setHighlighted:YES];

        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                               animated:YES 
                         scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

    else{
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        // [tableCell setHighlighted:NO];
    }

    return tableCell;

}
```

Comment: Sorry but where do I put the `[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`?

Comment: Also, you are right,the `setSelected` method acts funny, it only highlights everything that I highlighted once I select something else.

Comment: I tried this but sorry, it does not work. I display 20 rows but I have around 50 entries, when I check several entries on the first 20 entries and scroll down and select items at the bottom 20, the items I selected at the top 20 lose their highlight.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep several cells selected at the same time, you should consider setting `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;`